# iSync w/ Nokia 7705

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have all my phone saved in address book on my MAC (snow leopard) how do I transfer these phones over my new phone? I did pair it through bluetooth, although when I tried using iSync, I get "this device is not supported by isync"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to export all of your vCards out of address book and then using [vCard Splitter](http://homepage.mac.com/gaz/FileSharing13.html) to split that one file into multiple peaces and then using bluetooth you can upload to your phone!

Answer (score -1):

Try [The Missing Sync](http://www.markspace.com/products/symbian/ms-overview-mac.php) for Symbian by Mark/Space.

Comment: Nokia 7705 isn't running Symbian OS